# What is wrong with this simplistic hypothesis test for checking a power law relation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

I was reading a few resources regarding testing if the data follows a power law distribution (http://bactra.org/weblog/491.html and https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062) and became curious regarding a very basic doubt.

If we have a power law relation between Y and X, then that implies log(y) = C*log(x). Now if all X's are greater than 1, then log(x) is an infinite polynomial in (x-1). So should't that mean log(y) should be an infinite polynomial in (x-1)? In that case, why isn't simply running a polynomial regression with a large number of polynomial terms (ex. 40) and seeing if all of them are statistically significantly non-zero a good enough test for a power law (or at least rejecting one?).

That is, if I run a polyfit between log(y) and (x-1) with 40 terms and see that only the first three or four are significantly non-zero, is that good enough proof that my data doesn't follow a power law? Now, obviously this seems too easy to be true, but in that case what am I overlooking that renders the above test wrong?

Comment: Since "infinite polynomial" is not well-defined, it's hard to see how you might make any progress with this approach.  Take into consideration the fact that you are assured a perfect fit by the time the degree approaches the amount of data.

Comment: Well, but if not to check if it's a power law why can't it be used to reject that hypothesis? In case of my data I have 230,000 data points and on running a polyfit with 40 terms I get only the first 3 coefficients being non-zero with very small p-values. So in this specific case why isn't this a good enough way to reject the fact that the data follows a power law.

Comment: 1. Many things *other* than a power law will be writeable as an inifinite power series, so having lots of significant coefficients is no help. 2. An infinite power series might still have very small terms -- too small to be significant even with billions of points. If one wishes to design a null hypothesis significance test (or perhaps even some kind of equivalence test), it's best to consider what alternatives one wishes to have power against and design a test which is good at that task.